# Пришло уведомление что нужно удалить права READ_SMS and READ_CALL_LOG

Tags: android, android-sdk

Пришло уведомление что нужно удалить права READ_SMS and READ_CALL_LOG, но эти права мне нужно, я описал им в запросе который они мне отправили, но ответили что нужно удалить эти права, мое приложение считывает данные sms и звонков и выбирает подходящий тариф, требуют удалить запросы на эти разрешения, как мне быть, кто что сделал?

прислали ссылку в письме для чтения

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Comment: У Гугл ужесточились правила касательно доступа к звонкам и смс. С большой вероятностью права вам придется удалить... Но погуглите насчет новой политики, может есть дыры)

Comment: Придется удалить. Использовать можно для авторизации специальное API. Либо полный доступ только ланчерам и смс-приложениям

Comment: Google очень ужесточил правил. Можно вроде как модили написать, но с этим я так и не разобрался. Я одно приложение из-за этого вообще закрыл. А вот другому приложению отправляющему автоматически sms-ки сохранил жизнь. Подключил API для sms на [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/). Цены не кусаются, есть инструкции как подключиться к android, web и др. Там есть инструменты как на отправление sms так и на получение.

Answer (score 3):

Это один из самых сложных вопросов для разработчкив Андроид на текущий момент.
Из-за некоторых обстоятельств, была изменена политика конфиденциальности, которая урезала возможности использования разрешений категории READ_SMS и READ_CALL_LOG.
Единственный вариант, который позволяет сохранить возможность использовать данные разрешения, после получения данной формы - это еще раз выпустить новый релиз приложения, в котором нужно будет выбрать категорию, почему нужны эти разрешения. Но никаких гарантий успеха это не дает, на платформах Реддит, Медиум и т.д. идет активное обсуждение историй, когда одним разработчикам удавалось добиться своего, а вторым - нет. При том никакого шаблоного варианта успеха нет, по какому критерую в итоге все таки пропускают избранные приложения до сих пор не понятно (потому что нещадно удаляются даже приложения с высоким рейтингом и милионным количеством скачек). На Реддите даже есть история о том, как человеку сначала дали добро, а потом через 3 дня пришло новое сообщение, что в связи с новыми обстоятельствами прошлое решение анулируется, и в итоге разрешения использовать нельзя.
Так же есть проблемой то, что процесс рассмотрения данного вопроса довольно длительный, и может занимать несколько недель. Да и после этого рассмотрения зачастую приходит лаконичное сообщение "нет, нельзя" без какого-либо подробного описания. В итоге, остается лишь уповать на вариант избавления от разрешений, заменяя функциональность на [альтернативные решения](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827).